# Why doesn't TApplicationEvents.OnIdle get called?

Tags: delphi, event-handling

in my app I have a main form with a button.
Clicking this button, a form (not auto-created in dpr) is created and displayed; on this form, I placed a TApplicationEvents component and I defined its OnIdle event handler.
This event handler doesn't get called! May this depend because I derived this second form not from
TForm but from an other class, TChartBasicForm (by means of VFI)?
Thank you very much for replies.
Massimo.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is probably the least useful phrase in the history of debugging.  Do you mean that it isn't called at all?  Can you verify that by placing a breakpoint in the event handler and observing that it never breaks?  Or do you mean that it's doing something but not what you expected it to?

Comment: I wrote a quick test application, with VFI but not from TChartBasicForm and everything works as expected.  
Can you provide any more information?

Comment: Voted to close since it seems no longer relevant according to Massimo's own answer.

Comment: Smasher, I don't think that warrants closing this question. It's still relevant because the mistake Massimo made is one that anyone could make. It's not clear from the documentation that TApplicationEvents is not compatible with event handlers assigned directly to TApplication's events.

Answer (score 1):

Hooking an application's idle event can lead to a lot of debugging woes and other maintenance headaches, especially on a form other than the main form.  I realize this may not answer your specific question (which is hard to do at this point given the vagueness), but are you sure you can't accomplish what you're trying to do with a `TTimer` or `TThread` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for interest to all people.
"It doesn't work" means that it's not called at all.
Instead, the event OnShowHint works!

Ooops!
Perhaps I have understood the bad behaviour!
In the main form I defined a procedure like this one:

```
procedure IdleHandler(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
```

and in the FormCreate:

```
Application.OnIdle := IdleHandler;
```

This probably inhibits TApplicationEvents.OnIdle, even if
in IdleHandler, at the end of the procedure, I put:

```
Application.OnIdle := nil;
```

because the code is usefull to try a connection only at the begin
of the application.

I beg your pardon: my face is red......

Comment: The reason your actions caused TApplicationEvents to fail was that TApplicationEvents works by assigning *its own* methods to TApplication's events. When you assign your method directly to TApplication's event, you broke the link between it and the TApplicationEvents object. It's unfortunate, but that's just the way it works.